# How to effectively attack enemy champions with a ranged champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

My problem is I have a hard time winning auto-atack battles.

I don't know how to chase while attacking with my ADC. I "right-click" Draven continuously while chasing, and sometimes he stops to run and my Ashe run toward Draven until melee range, and then start to attack. I think that I am missing some right clicks.

I searched the web about advanced controlling the champion, and I learn about the "A" key and click the target, or Shift+Click to attack-move, but I don't know what the best or ideal way to do it.

Maybe I'm just nervous when in the heat of the battle, but if it is case of practice, I want to start to practice the correct way to make it.

I thank you any help!

Comment: Shift+A makes your champion focus on the closest target, the best way to attack is explained by asterlune, by right click target then move, repeatedly as fast as you can without canceling your AA. its all about mouse accuracy.

Comment: I believe there is a shortcut for moving while AAing, never used but I assume it will be cancelling your animation and resume to move, but (again) I _assume_ if you don't turn this off you will stop moving to attack even when you are trying to escape possibly dying in the process

Comment: my answer on this question. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166437/what-are-the-mechanics-for-attack-move. Covers what you asked about and gives more information

Answer (score 3):

At the most basic level (to avoid not attacking)- you don't need to click continuously; just right click once and your champion will attack until you tell them to do something else.

Eventually (and this really isn't important now, but I include it to not lead you astray in the long run) you'll find that this is slightly sub-optimal when chasing, because your champion will only walk forward when actually out of range, which is problem when you're not out of range but soon will be. In this situation, you should manually walk forward after each attack. You'll need familiarity with the champion in question to know exactly how early in the attack animation you can move without canceling it.

Comment: -1, since the whole point of the question is about the 'advanced' ways to chase, while you heavily downplay it in your answer. I'll undo the -1 if you change it and ping me.

Comment: @Schism I was mostly answering "I "right-click" Draven continuously while chasing, and sometimes he stops to run and my Ashe run toward Draven until melee range, and then start to attack. I think that I am missing some right clicks.", which strongly implies that basic control is what the question is asking after. The advanced kiting bit really is a fringe thing compared to attacking continuously.

Comment: I see. Still, I don't see any harm in expanding your answer to detail how to attack-move effectively and cancel animations. (I can't undo the -1 now anyway.)

Comment: +1 I find myself spam right clicking a target and if i miss even one it could be my death.

Answer (score 1):

**The key is to move while attacking.**

If you keep right-clicking the champion you will do more while running at him than just shooting. The key is to click *ahead* of him, after you shoot him.

In order to do this, you shoot, then while your shoot is recharging, you right click ahead of him to keep moving.

If you do this properly you will be able to hit him *many* more times.